Gong WPF Highlight/Select dropped (custom way) ListBox item
Description of the bug:
I want to drop a ListBox element exactly from where it was picked up and it doesn't work.
PropertyViewModel.cs =
private void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs? e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII");
    if (e.Source is FrameworkElement element && element.DataContext is PropertyViewModel propertyViewModel)
    {
     
        
        Point mousePosition = e.GetPosition(element);



        propertyViewModel.MouseOffset = new Point(
            mousePosition.X,
            mousePosition.Y
        );

        //Debug.WriteLine("MouseOffset: " + propertyViewModel.MouseOffset);
    }
}

TemplateGeneratorViewModel.cs =
 public void Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo)
 {

     if (dropInfo.Data is PropertyViewModel originalProperty && dropInfo.VisualTarget is ListBox listBox)
     {
         Point dropPosition = dropInfo.DropPosition;
         Debug.WriteLine("DROP: " + dropPosition);
         if (listBox.Name == CanvasListBoxName)
         {
             if (!originalProperty.IsOnCanvas)
             {

              CloneItemToCanvas(originalProperty, dropPosition);
                 //DragDrop.DefaultDropHandler.Drop(dropInfo);
             }
             else
             {
              var newPosition = new Point(
               dropPosition.X - originalProperty.MouseOffset.X,
               dropPosition.Y - originalProperty.MouseOffset.Y);

                 originalProperty.X = (int)(newPosition.X);
                 originalProperty.Y = (int)(newPosition.Y);
             }
         }
         else if (listBox.Name == PropertyListBoxName && originalProperty.IsOnCanvas)
         {
             // Move the item back to the property list if needed
             originalProperty.IsOnCanvas = false;
             CanvasItems.Remove(originalProperty);
         }
     }

     
 }

Expected behavior
Just to drop the element from where it was picked up relative to the mouse by using Gong's Drop() WPF function.
I have been stuck for days and I don't know what to do... Thanks for your time.

Yes, that's what I'm trying to do, but I'm not able. The item is selected behind, but the blue border is not shown.

Hi, are you still here?? I will update the code.
